# MYSQL: Count type for user id

Tags: mysql

Please refer the db table image.

[image]

I want to count type with value 'Q' for each user id. I am confused either whatever I have written is correct or not.

```
"SELECT COUNT(type),userid FROM '$db_prefix'posts WHERE type=Q GROUP BY userid";
```

So where it will display total number of Q for x user id like below :

```
userid 1 has 25 Q
userid 2 has 11 Q
....
```

Same way for A and C but I think if I will get for Q than it will work in the same way for A and C.

Comment: Sounds correct to me; any errors? What's the outcome?

Comment: its giving `Notice: Use of undefined constant type - assumed 'type'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually get it for each type with a single query. Like this:

```
SELECT type, userid, COUNT(*) AS `n` FROM posts GROUP BY type, userid;
```

This query groups those rows that have the same value of BOTH type and userid.

Echo statement:

`echo $q['userid'] .' has '. $q['n'] $q['type'] .' question';`

Comment: Unquoted identifiers cannot contain `'` characters.

Comment: You get the idea. 
I'd edit it, but the query looks untidy as a string constant in quotation marks.

Comment: giving error `Notice: Use of undefined constant type - assumed 'type'`

Comment: The issue is with the DB prefix. I've edited my query to just work with the table name. Just modify it to execute in the required DB.

Comment: ah that was stupid mistake in whileloop but after that error gone but it is not rendering total count. `echo $q['userid'] .' has '. $q['type'] .' question';` by the way i want only total 'Q' count

Comment: Okay, if you just want the 'Q' count, reinclude the `WHERE type='Q'` clause.
However include both `type` and `userid` in your `GROUP BY` clause, that's the technically correct way to write the query because both columns are included in `SELECT`.

Comment: I have edited the query to select number of columns as 'n'.
So here's your echo statement:

`echo $q['userid'] .' has '. $q['n'] $q['type'] .' question';`

Answer (score 3):

This query is ok:

```
select count(type), userid
from posts
where type='Q'
group by userid
```

You forgot the quotes on the  **'**Q *'**

This query does all the letter in one shot.

```
select userid, type, count(*) as count
from posts
group by userid, type
```

Comment: so where I am wrong? Am I using wrong code to output? `echo $q['userid'] .' has '. $q['type'] .' question';`

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT userid, type, COUNT(*) 
FROM {$db_prefix}posts 
GROUP BY userid, type"
```

Comment: Unquoted identifiers cannot contain `'` characters.

Comment: That's still unquoted: you've just put the entire query within a string.  If the table name really does contain `'` characters, you'd need to quote the identifier with backticks.  But I suspect it's just a misunderstanding of the higher level language's syntax; if it's PHP, for example, perhaps the OP just wants `{$db_prefix}posts`.

Comment: same error for everyone `Notice: Use of undefined constant type - assumed 'type'`

Comment: @pixelngrain: Are you using PHP?  Did you try `{$db_prefix}posts` as suggested in my comment above?

Comment: Yes I am using PHP and my table prefix is qa_ so it should be qa_posts and i have resolve other error too but not rendering total count or `Q` yet. using this `echo $q['userid'] .' has '. $q['type'] .' question';` may be I am using wrong code to output